# Run same tests in different environment in Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

Ultimately the function i want to test has the same functionality when used in node or web. However internally the function is written in a different way for node and web so i need to test both of them. Because the functionality is identical i dont want to write the same tests twice. Consider this (lets assume the insides of the function is different):

```
// mylib/node/index.ts
export function add(a: number, b: number) {
  return a+b
}
```

```
// mylib/web/index.ts
export function add(a: number, b: number) {
  return a+b
}
```

To test it im doing:

```
// nodeAdd.test.ts
/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */
import { add } from './mylib/node'

test('addition', () => {
  expect(add(1, 2)).toEqual(3)
})
```

```
// webAdd.test.ts
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
import { add } from './mylib/web'

test('addition', () => {
  expect(add(1, 2)).toEqual(3)
})
```

So the tests are identical however it is ran in a different environment and imported from a different location. Is it possible to write the test once and test for both envs?

Comment: If you are using a monorepo, you could create a common file test where the function `add` could be injected depending on your environment. You could wrap your test in a function having as parameter function you'd want to test.

Comment: Could you show me an example how to implement it based on my add function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer based on my comment on the question.

```
// mylib/common/index.ts
export const commonAddTest = (add: (a: number, b: number) => number) => {
  test('addition', () => {
    expect(add(1, 2)).toEqual(3)
  })
}
```

```
// nodeAdd.test.ts
/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */
import { commonAddTest } from './mylib/common'
import { add } from './mylib/node'

commonAddTest(add)
```

```
// webAdd.test.ts
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
import { commonAddTest } from './mylib/common'
import { add } from './mylib/web'

commonAddTest(add)
```

Comment: thanks, created a small tests generator based on your answer for same functionality but different target functions